# To show that $\cosh(\overline{z})=\overline{\cosh{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $\cosh(\overline{z})=\overline{\cosh{z}}$

Can someone help me out to find the solution?

Comment: What definitions of $\cosh$ do you know with which you could play around with? What does the bar notation mean (conjugation) ? Ask yourself these questions and you might be able to work it out.

Answer (score 3):

From $\overline{e^z}=\overline{e^{x+iy}}=e^{x-iy}=e^{\overline{z}}$, you obtain $$\overline{\cosh{z}}=\overline{\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}}= {\frac{e^\overline{z}+e^{-\overline{z}}}{2}}  = \cosh(\overline{z})$$

Comment: yeah u mention them clearly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

More general: if $f$ is an entire function such that in the power series representation

$f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$

the coefficients $a_n$ are real, then

$\overline{f(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\overline{z}^n=f(\overline{z})$.

Comment: That general form made me understand better about the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the important thing to note here is that complex conjugation is continuous, i.e. $z_n \to z \Rightarrow \overline{z_n} \to \overline{z}$ or written differently:
$$\overline{\lim z_n} = \lim \overline{z_n}$$
Therefore, if $\sum a_n z$ is the series expansion of $\cosh$, it follows that
$$\overline{\cosh(z)}=\overline{\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n z} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \overline{\sum_{n=0}^N a_n z} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \overline{z} = \cosh(z)$$
since the coefficients $a_n$ are real numbers in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\cosh(x+iy)=e^xe^{iy}+e^{-x}e^{-iy},$$

$$2\cosh(\overline{x+iy})=\cosh(x-iy)=e^xe^{-iy}+e^{-x}e^{iy}=e^x\overline{e^{iy}}+e^{-x}\overline{e^{iy}}=\overline{e^xe^{iy}+e^{-x}e^{-iy}}.$$

Comment: Lets say, if we use sin(z), is it similar with that cosh(z) that equivalent to e^(x)e^(iy) +e^(-x)e^(-iy) ?

Comment: @JonSirNo: don't get your question, can you rephrase ?